# How did Trent walk through the wall in The Long Run?

Tags: novel, daniel-keys-moran

In The Long Run, at the end of a chase sequence, the main character, Trent, apparently evades his pursuers by walking through a wall and escaping.  I knew someone who insisted that he figured out how Trent did it by reading the book carefully, but I've read it twice and I absolutely didn't see any real clues.  Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear whether he did or didn't, but one thing is clear: he *didn't* use the emblade to cut a hole and fix it.  DKM [has said exactly this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/rec.arts.sf.written/7tZWpyS2GIc/NERCtEYt0scJ):

> Simon Tong (stong@ariel) mentioned that people were arguing about this 
>   over here -- this being the damn wall again.
>
> Relax, okay? Think whatever you like about it. David Gerrold thought 
>   that Trent had walked through the wall (and was pissed that I hadn't set 
>   up Trent's ability to do so more thoroughly); Amy Stout, my former editor 
>   at Bantam who I love and who is one of the very nicest people I've ever 
>   met, decided instantly upon reading the mss. that Trent had never walked 
>   through the wall, that it was a holograph set up by Ralf the Wise and 
>   Powerful.
>
> All I'm really inclined to say about it is, I ain't saying.
>
> I will say that one argument I've been told about is incorrect. Trent 
>   did not cut through the wall with an emblade, and then display a holof of 
>   the wall over the hole in the wall. The wall was solid. So ... **either 
>   Trent walked through the wall, or Ralf animated a holo of him walking 
>   through the wall.**
>
> It's not an accident, BTW, that all that setup regarding the holo 
>   theory is there. By the time of the AI War, Mohammed Vance has figured 
>   out that it was just a holo, and tells Trent so just before killing him.
>
> Whether that's a correct deduction or not, I ain't saying.

Comment: Weird.  That is a very strange setup for an author - to leave it 100% unknowable, and have the seemingly most reasonable guess be wrong, but also have that it is wrong be almost unknowable via just the canon text - but I guess when he says it, we have to believe him.

Comment: Not at all strange--see "Blade Runner", "Life of Pi", or even "The Lady or the Tiger".

Comment: Do you have examples from those where there is a mystery that is unknowable from the movie/book, but is knowable from the author's statement?  Certainly, in Blade Runner for example, there is plenty that is left open to audience interpretation.  But nothing (that I know of) where the author says "no, that interpretation is wrong; it is, in fact, this...despite the fact that there is no evidence for it."

Comment: I still think Blade Runner fits your question: "Is Deckard a replicant?" is unknowable from the movie itself, and Ridley Scott has provided a definitive answer after the fact.

LOST is another pretty close example.  There are enough mysteries that weren't wrapped up definitively that there are multiple theories about them, and Damon Lindelof has put a number of them down by fiat (see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FvnNF-NWmc4).

In that case, though, I believe that it's a question of poor storytelling consistency rather than intentional ambiguity. :-)

Answer (score 2):

At this point in the narrative, Trent still has the emblade and glue that he earlier used to make and (almost invisibly) repair a hole in a floor/ceiling. The room in which the event occurs is a briefing room that we have previously been told is equipped with holo projectors. You do the maths.

Comment: I've thought about this for a while, and I was thinking that the projectors must be involved.  I guess I didn't remember the emblade?  I can't see anything wrong with this theory, and it makes sense, so...

Comment: DKM's most recent book [The A.I. War: Book 1](http://www.amazon.com/The-A-I-War-Book-ebook/dp/B004XMR5A4) has some discussion on this and talks about how he couldn't have used the holo. It says an Elite would have "seen the grain in even a modern holo" (see Chapter 25).